# How to stub the next-auth signIn method in Cypress

Tags: node.js, cypress, next.js13, next-auth

I'm writing tests for a component that is calling the signIn method. I'm just trying to stub the method with Cypress so test that it is being called, but I can't find the right parameters for the stub method.

I have my component:

```js
export default function Button() {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => signIn('cognito')}
    >
      Login to Cognito
    </button>
  );
}
```

And I have my Cypress test

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/react';

import LoginButton from '../LoginButton';

describe('Login Button Component Tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.mount(<Button />);
  });

  it('should render the "Login to Vendor Portal" button', () => {
    cy.get('button').should('have.text', 'Login to Cognito');
  });

  it('should call signIn function with "cognito" when the button is clicked', () => {
    cy.window().then(() => {
      cy.stub(NextAuth, 'signIn').as('signInStub');
    });

    cy.get('button').click();

    cy.get('@signInStub').should('be.calledWith', 'cognito');
  });
});
```

And all I'm getting is errors on the stub method: `Error: Trying to stub property 'signIn' of undefined`

Comment: You should take a look at this comment https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/17048#issuecomment-1607493564. Theres an experimental plugin you can use to allow mocking ESM imports in cypress component tests. And then you would need to import the module like `import * as NextAuth from 'next-auth/react'` and then do the same stub line you have now with that.